# How to increase your 'mathStack' reputation quickly?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I ask this to gather ideas and advice on how to increase your reputation in a constant and sustainable way.

And would you necessarily need to be a professor or a post-doc to have more than 10k ?

Comment: 1. post a lot of interesting questions; post a lot of really good answers. 2. No.

Comment: Qiaochu Yuan has over 388K reputation points, mostly received when he was an undergraduate and graduate student.

Comment: I would suggest that you focus on the math part and take this website as a great place to learn and let others learn math via questions and answers. In this process reps will be gained without much trouble. Don't try to make earning reps as your main objective.

Comment: Yes I noticed that posting questions rewards more points that answering them.

Comment: See also: [How do we earn reputation more easily?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29550)

Comment: $2.$, *very much no*. I am not at university yet, but have $18$k. I am just committed to learning and teaching on this site; really, though this site is large, it is also quite a small world. The only people who regularly contribute (and thus, get reputation) are those who care strongly about learning, teaching, community or all three. But reputation is much less important than caring!

Comment: @NotaChoice Hmm, answers tend to gain much more attention and votes than questions. Indeed, many very well-written and thought through questions get hardly any votes at all

Comment: @ParamanandSingh This question also reveals insights on the reputation system.

Comment: @FShrike yes! Well, and do you think that there is some pattern of the topics that gets more answers than others?

Comment: Let’s put it this way. My most popular answers - in terms of upvotes - have been some of my most trivial. If a question is about integration, differentiation or basic real analysis, it gets disproportionate amounts of attention because far more people know about these topics then they do, say, the kinds of questions I tend to ask. But there’s no sense in gaming the integration questions to earn more, since they’re popular but also intensely difficult (usually)

Comment: @Arturo  I'd suggest revising to "post a lot of really good answers to decent questions meeting site standards."

Comment: @amWhy I usually consider "meeting the site standards" a prerequisite for "good"...

Comment: Indeed, @Arturo.  I wasn't faulting you, and I shouldn't have added my comment. But I did upvote your comment.

Answer (score 12):

Have you noticed all the down votes your question received? This is (probably) because people who put gaining rep over creating a good experience for others, and having a good experience themselves, often make the place worse for others, posting content of debatable quality in the pursuit of points, and creating squabbles on meta as they debate every rep point.

Hopefully you're not the type of person to do that, but we have seen this in the past, so I thought it worth mentioning.

(Also, I'm not saying rep. points are meaningless. I did a little "yipee" when I just broke 6k, and I'm kinda bummed that I don't get any new privileges until I hit 10k, which probably won't happen for a few years. But I'm not going to start lowering the quality of my contributions here to get there faster.)

Comment: I am not aware of the past as I am here for the last two years only !

Comment: And I don't get why all of the downvotes to be honest, it seems like most of them read the question with judging or putting their own interpretation of the question. Nothing is taken on 2nd or 3rd level!

Comment: Most of the effort on the main site is spent trying to figure out intent based on minimal information provided by posters. As you have given almost no context, or said what use you wish to make of this information, are you surprised people try to figure it out themselves? And are trying to figure out what effect it could have on the quality of the site? And are providing answers that would discourage any one reading them from doing things that would reduce the quality?

Comment: Excellent answer, @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC.